# Are there any alignment restrictions for Zhentarim members in Adventurer's League?

Tags: dnd-5e, alignment, dnd-adventurers-league

I was wondering if there were any specific rules in D&D 5e (Adventurer's League) with regards to alignment for members of the Zhentarim.

When looking at the Wizard's website, the DMG and the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, I can't find any specific rules nor guidelines as to alignment restrictions.

The only mention I can find is in the Adventurer's League Player's Guide v3.0, where it states: "The following alignments are not allowed in the D&D Adventurers League: Neutral evil, Chaotic evil. In addition, the following alignment is restricted to Lords’ Alliance or Zhentarim faction characters only:
Lawful evil."(page 4).

Can I take this to mean that, if you want to be Lawful Evil, you must be a member of either Lords' Alliance or Zhentarim, but that any other alignment (other than Neutral evil and Chaotic evil) is also acceptable for a member of Zhentarim?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes, alignment is restricted in Adventurers League.**

You've quoted the correct portion of the [AL Player's Guide](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/ALPGv3.pdf).

1. NE and CE are outright banned.
2. LE is allowable for either a member of Lords' Alliance or a member of Zhentarim only.
3. all other alignments are playable by any faction. *Including Zhent.*

This alignment restriction has appeared in the same form in each of the three seasons to date.

Comment: Interesting. Given the description of the faction, I can't imagine a LG Zhent.

Comment: @Adeptus sure it may not be likely, but I'm sure they didn't want to limit it in case a player could make it work (undercover agent, maybe?). They only restrict things when it often proves to be detrimental to the gaming experience.